# How can I create a new Role in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am trying to create a role in SharePoint 2013 but I am unable to find any kind of option to create a new role. I don't want to create group. I know there is difference between role and group. I have created roles and groups using SharePoint 2013 client library code, but now I want to create role manually in SharePoint 2013.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand this correctly but I am suggesting you a few things:

Supposing that you have access to the site permissions, you could navigate to ***Site Settings*** -> ***Site permissions*** (under Users and Permissions). In the ribbon you find the **Permission Levels** button and once you click it you will go to a page where you can add new permission levels or maybe edit/delete the existing ones.

When you create/edit a permission level, you can choose what kind of permission that permission level will have, for instance, "Add/Delete Items Items" for list permissions or "Create sub-sites/groups"

I would refer you to this link [Use SharePoint permission management to create various roles in an app for SharePoint](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/officeapps/2013/09/25/use-sharepoint-permission-management-to-create-various-roles-in-an-app-for-sharepoint/)

Comment: New role can be created by adding a permission level in SharePoint 2013. So, there is no option like new role in SharePoint.Thanks Murilo